# Insert total group of prior group at the end of a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting

I just want to move a column grouped from the first column to the end of my matrix.

I don't need any total of each row of the subgroup that I created.

The results should be like this:
[image: The results should be like this]

Here is the model of my matrix:
[image: Here is the model of my matrix]

As you can see here I'm summarizing all the rows inside in a group.
Here are the results
[image: Here are the results]

Answer (score 1):

I will use a sample dataset to mimic your design

```
SELECT  'rg1' As rowgroup1, 'rg1.1' as rowgroup2, 'cg1' as columngroup1, 20 as kg, 150 as rvalue   UNION ALL
SELECT  'rg1' As rowgroup1, 'rg1.2' as rowgroup2, 'cg1' as columngroup1, 40 as kg, 240 as rvalue   UNION ALL
SELECT  'rg2' As rowgroup1, 'rg2.1' as rowgroup2, 'cg2' as columngroup1, 25 as kg, 180 as rvalue   UNION ALL
SELECT  'rg2' As rowgroup1, 'rg2.2' as rowgroup2, 'cg2' as columngroup1, 18 as kg, 100 as rvalue   UNION ALL
SELECT  'rg2' As rowgroup1, 'rg2.3' as rowgroup2, 'cg2' as columngroup1, 15 as kg, 90 as rvalue
```

I will create a matrix with no totals after each group and a total column for each row (gray column)

[image]

Now for my total rvalue column I will use an expression which will display the total only on the last row of the group

```
=Iif( 
RunningValue(Fields!rvalue.Value, Sum, "rowgroup1") = SUM(Fields!rvalue.Value, "rowgroup1")
, SUM(Fields!rvalue.Value, "rowgroup1"), 
Nothing)
```

To make it look like one cell, for the rtotal value cell, set the top border to none and for the bottom border you can use an expression to be solid only for the last group row

```
=Iif( 
RunningValue(Fields!rvalue.Value, Sum, "rowgroup1") = SUM(Fields!rvalue.Value, "rowgroup1")
, "Solid"
, "None"
)
```

[image]

Comment: I found a solution similar as yours.
I changed my script to have only 1 row  and 2 columns (before I had 2 lines for each column, I removed the sub-group and added a new line for the new column.
But like you said that not possible to merge this cells for the totals (we can survive without merging ;) )
It is a shame that Microsoft doesn't fix some simple problems like to let us to move the groups to the right side.

Comment: There are also other solutions with tablix nesting if you want to experiment, column1 with rowgroup - columnw with nested tablix- column3 with group total, but I consider this to be more simple